# Jasper fonts on linux

Tags: linux, jasper-reports

My .jasper report made using verdana on windows does not work on the client running tomcat under red hat linux.

Is there any way to link the verdana.ttf to the .jasper, or the only way around this is to install verdana.ttf on the server side?
Is there any other solution?

Comment: You should use [Font Extensions](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/sample.reference/fonts/index.html) mechanism.

Comment: thank you. it was easier than i thought it would be.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lower level alternative. You can unzip the jar `jasperreports-fonts-x.x.x.jar` in the lib directory of jasper server's.

Check the structure and edit/add the appropriate XML files and the TTF files you need. Maintain coherence in what's in there.

I was having troubles including fonts every time so I did that and only have to worry on the next upgrade :)

Hope it helps, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

- Create file jasperreports_extension.properties with this content:

  net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.fonts= net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionsRegistryFactory
  net.sf.jasperreports.extension.simple.font.families.fontfamily=
      fonts/fontfamily.xml
- If you use maven, include this file as a resource in your pom.xml
- Create a file fontfamily.xml with this content:

> ```
>    <fontfamilies>
>       <fontfamily name="Verdana">
>       <normal><![CDATA[fonts/verdana.ttf]]></normal>
>       <bold><![CDATA[fonts/verdanabd.ttf]]></bold>
>       <italic><![CDATA[fonts/verdanai.ttf]]></italic>
>       <bolditalic><![CDATA[fonts/verdanabi.ttf]]></bolditalic>
>       <pdfembedded><![CDATA[true]]></pdfembedded>
>       </fontfamily>
>     </fontfamilies>
> ```

- Put in folder "fonts" (create this folder) all ttf files (download for example from http://www.fontsupply.com/fonts/V/Verdana.html)
- Use fontName Verdana in all your Jasper Reports (*.jrxml)